# A curve has infinitely many points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f\in k[x,y]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. I would like to prove the curve $f(x,y)=0$ has infinitely many points. What I know is $k$ is infinite, but I don't know how to use this to prove this curve has infinite points.

Shafarevich speaks about this in [Basic Algebraic Geometry 1: Varieties in Projective Space](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642379559) on the page 4, so I suppose this should be trivial.

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286352/polynomial-with-infinitely-many-zeros

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need the hypothesis that $f$ is (either zero or) nonconstant. Assume WLOG that $f(x, y)$ is nonconstant in $x$. Write $f(x, y) = x^n g(y) + \text{lower terms}$ where $x^n$ is the highest order term in $x$ and $g(y)$ is a nonzero polynomial in $y$. For all but finitely many values $y_0$ of $y$, $g(y_0)$ is nonzero, so for all but finitely many values $y_0$ of $y$, $f(x, y_0)$ is a nonconstant polynomial in $x$ and hence has a root.

Comment: What about the non-constant polynomial $f(x,y)=nx+1$ over $\mathbb{C}$? The corresponding curve has only one point.

Comment: @uniquesolution: no, the points are $(-1/n, y)$ for any $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : for all $y \in k$, consider the polynomial $P_y(X) = f(X,y) \in k[X]$.